# Excel VBA DBEngine.CreateWorkspace fails saying cannot load DLL

Tags: excel, vba, windows-8, odbc, dao

I have a legacy business application written in VBA in Excel. It uses the VBA DAO library (installed at `c:\program files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll`) and the classes `Workspace`, `Database`, `DBEngine`, `Connection`) to connect to a SQL database via ODBC.

It works properly up to Windows 7, but on Windows 8 /Server 2012, it doesn't work, on the very first call to DAO:

```
Set ws = DBEngine.CreateWorkspace(wsName, "", "", dbUseODBC)
```

raises a runtime error number 3633 description `"Cannot load DLL: 'msrdo20.dll'"`. This occurs both in the class library's `DBEngine.Errors` and the regular VBA `Err` object.

This error occurs whether or not the file `msrdo20.dll` exists.

I found
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/260369
which says to include ODBCDirect, but that doesn't seem to be relevant.

I found
http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-172385.html
which suggests removing Microsoft DAO 3.6 from the references and switching to DAO 3.5 -- but doing that breaks things even worse, I get run-time error 429, "ActiveX component can't create object".

This is Windows Server 2012, Excel 2013.

Comment: Are you using the same architecture across different OS? Also are you loading the dll via Tools->References or using `Declare` ?

Comment: It's not my code loading the DLL; it's dynamically loaded from within the DAO package (dao360.dll). It appears to be a COM DLL that needs to be registered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This blog solved that problem for me:

http://pwaldman.com/unable-to-load-msrdo20-dll-or-rdocurs-dll/

Extract:

Resolution

1. Download Service Pack 6 for Visual Basic 6.0 (Vs6sp6.exe)

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9183

2. Run Vs6sp6.exe and extract the files
3. Open msrdo20.cab, it contains the following files: MSRDO20.DLL, MSRDO20.INF, and RDOCURS.DLL. Extract all three files and copy them to the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ directory.
4. Open an elevated(admin) command prompt, navigate to C:\Windows\SysWOW64, and register MSRDO20.DLL. The RDOCURS.DLL does not need to be registered.

   ```
    C:\Windows\System32> cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64
    C:\Windows\SysWOW64> regsvr32 MSRDO20.DLL
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had discovered I had to register MSRDO20.dll but I didn't know the proper way to download it (googling just led to dozens of spammy-looking sites)

Comment: Hint: Make sure to read _**elevated** command prompt_ in the answer above - that is run the command prompt as administrator! Took me some time to figure this out.

Comment: The folder is called `SysWOW64` in Windows 10 (instead of `Sys64WOW`)

Answer (score 0):

I had forgotten to run my command prompt as administrator when I used regsvr32. That's why VBA wasn't able to find the DLL.